# IntelliJ IDEA properties

Tags: intellij-idea

In my project I'm frequently passing one AccountID in different packages and classes and that accountid is hardcoded wherever it used.

This AccountID may change for some resons in the future. And in order not to go over all files in my my project and replace it, I want to write it in one place.

I heard that there are some `properties` in `IntelliJ` where I can do that. I don't know how to google my problem, so if you have any sources, please share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use the `Properties.class` for that purpose.

just write a txt file anywere (I recomend your Resources folder) and name it to "`myProperties.properties`" for instance

The text in your propertiefile would look like the following:

```
AccountID = "whateverIDyouWant"
```

to get the data of your propertiefile call:

```
Properties props = new Properties();

 FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("G:\\your\\path\\myProperties.properties");
      props.load(in);
      in.close();
      String AccountID = props.getProperty("AccountID");
```

if your AccountID is an `int` just parse your string using `Integer.parseInt(yourString)`;

if you want to set your properties through hard code, that can also be done:

```
props.setProperty("AccountID", "whateverIDyouWant");
```

**Edit:** 
to create a resources folder, create a folder in your classpath. Afterwards go to the "Project view" in IntelliJ. Rightclick the new folder and select "Mark directory as" -> "Sources Root". Thats how its done.